# Out of Memory errors in MATLAB NN Toolbox and data division problems in training datasets

Tags: neural-network, out-of-memory, matlab

I am facing problem in running huge data set in matlab NN Toolbox- the problem is-> when i use trainlm algorithm, NN Toolbox fails to run the data and shows Out of memory error, but for other algorithms there is no memory problem. Why is this so? Moreover when i put hidden neuron more than 15 it also shows out of memory. How to solve this kind of problems?

One more thing: i put 10, 45, 45 % data division for training -validation and testing, but after running the codes i found that in the workspace it executed 25% data for training, 37% data for validation, and 37% data for testing purpose. How to resolve this issue?

Do anybody have idea how to solve this kind of problems? I will be glad to have the comments and any kind of suggestion. Thanks.

I am using R2010b version of MATLAB in my laptop which is running in Windows 7.

Here is the code i used for training the dataset

```
EX_355 = xlsread('Training Dataset.xlsx','B2:B435106');

EX_532 = xlsread('Training Dataset.xlsx','C2:C435106');

BA_355 = xlsread('Training Dataset.xlsx','D2:D435106');

BA_532 = xlsread('Training Dataset.xlsx','E2:E435106');

BA_1064 = xlsread('Training Dataset.xlsx','F2:F435106');

Reff = xlsread('Training Dataset.xlsx','G2:G435106');

Input(1,:) = EX_355;

Input(2,:) = EX_532;

Input(3,:) = BA_355;

Input(4,:) = BA_532;

Input(5,:) = BA_1064;

Target(1,:) = Reff;

net = feedforwardnet;

net = configure(net,Input,Target);

net = init(net);

inputs = Input;

targets = Target;

hiddenLayerSize = 10;

net = fitnet(hiddenLayerSize);

net.inputs{1}.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapminmax'};

net.outputs{2}.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapminmax'};

net.divideFcn = 'dividerand';

net.divideMode = 'sample';

net.divideParam.trainRatio = 10/100;

net.divideParam.valRatio = 45/100;

net.divideParam.testRatio = 45/100;

net.trainFcn = 'trainlm';

net.performFcn = 'mse';

net.plotFcns = {'plotperform','plottrainstate','ploterrhist', ... 'plotregression', 'plotfit'};

[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);

outputs = net(inputs);

errors = gsubtract(targets,outputs);

performance = perform(net,targets,outputs)

trainTargets = targets .* tr.trainMask{1};

valTargets = targets .* tr.valMask{1};

testTargets = targets .* tr.testMask{1};

net.trainParam.epochs;

net.trainParam.time;

net.trainParam.goal;

net.trainParam.min_grad;

net.trainParam.mu_max;

net.trainParam.max_fail;

net.trainParam.show;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

paste this before "train"

```
net.efficiency.memoryReduction = NUMBER;
```

change this number till the code run

you can increment from 1 --> inf

more description is available @ http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/train-the-network.html

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/nnet/ug/optimize-neural-network-training-speed-and-memory.html

This is a quote from MathWorks:

> If MATLAB is being used and memory limitations are a problem, the amount of temporary storage needed can be reduced by a factor of N, in exchange for performing the computations N times sequentially on each of N subsets of the data.

```
net2 = train(net1,x,t,'reduction',N);
```

> This is called memory reduction.

Keep increasing the value of N till your code runs.